# R - using bind_rows for list of subsetted objects

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a list of tens of objects of the structure below. I would like to drop the first three rows of every file and keep only the first three columns.

```
    x<-structure(c("", "Service", "", "HR", "", "", "Function", "", "Code", 
                "X1", "", "", "", "", "", "Doe, John", "Roe, Jane", 
                "Doe, Jane", "", "Full name", "", "", "", ""), .Dim = c(6L, 4L))

    y<-structure(c("", "Service", "", "IT", "", "", "Function", "", "Code", 
                "X2", "", "", "", "", "", "Doe, Johnny", "Roe, Janette", 
                "Doe, Janette", "", "Full name", "", "", "", ""), .Dim = c(6L, 4L))

    z<-structure(c("", "Service", "", "RD", "", "", "Function", "", "Code", 
                "X3", "", "", "", "", "", "Doe, Johnny", "Roe, Janette", 
                "Roe, Johnny", "", "Full name", "", "", "", ""), .Dim = c(6L, 4L))

l<-list(x,y,z)
```

How can I generalise what is written below for all objects in the the list with `length(l)` ?

```
length(l)

x<-bind_rows(
tbl_df(l[[1]][-c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3)]),
tbl_df(l[[2]][-c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3)]),
tbl_df(l[[3]][-c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3)])
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bind_rows` can accept a list of data frames; So you can loop through the list, subset the matrices and convert them to data frames, then `bind_rows` should work on the result list:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lapply(l, function(mat) tbl_df(mat[-(1:3), 1:3])))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#     V1    V2           V3
#  <chr> <chr>        <chr>
#1    HR    X1    Doe, John
#2                Roe, Jane
#3                Doe, Jane
#4    IT    X2  Doe, Johnny
#5             Roe, Janette
#6             Doe, Janette
#7    RD    X3  Doe, Johnny
#8             Roe, Janette
#9              Roe, Johnny
```

---

Another option is to use `do.call(rbind, ...)` which results in a matrix (if you don't care being a matrix or data frame):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(l, `[`, -(1:3), 1:3))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]          
# [1,] "HR" "X1" "Doe, John"   
# [2,] ""   ""   "Roe, Jane"   
# [3,] ""   ""   "Doe, Jane"   
# [4,] "IT" "X2" "Doe, Johnny" 
# [5,] ""   ""   "Roe, Janette"
# [6,] ""   ""   "Doe, Janette"
# [7,] "RD" "X3" "Doe, Johnny" 
# [8,] ""   ""   "Roe, Janette"
# [9,] ""   ""   "Roe, Johnny"
```